# How to find the largest and the second largest in a array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array and I'm trying to find the largest and second-largest number in an array but with my code

```
void FindNum(int arr[],int size){
int first;
int second;

for (int i = 0;i<size;i++){
  first = max(first,arr[i]);
}

cout<<"Largest number is "<<first<<endl;
for(int i =0; i<size;i++){
  if(arr[i] != first)
    second =max(second,arr[i]);
}
 cout<<"Second largest is "<<second<<endl;
}

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int nums[] = {13,15,4,16,3,11,6,18};


int n = (sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]));
FindNum(nums,n);
}
```

The output for the second comes out to be  32681

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If you run it multiple times, you may notice that `second` keeps changing which means you have not initialized `first` and `second`.  They will likely be pointing to random numbers in memory, probably just luck that `first` gives the correct answer.  Also the `include` and `using` should be at the start of the program.  I couldn't get it to compile without moving them.

Comment: @silicontrip thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate through the array and store the 2 biggest values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

int main() {
    int biggest = INT_MIN; // initial value
    int secondBiggest = INT_MIN;  // initial value
    int nums[] = {/*Some value*/ };
    const int n = (sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (nums[i] > biggest) {
            secondBiggest = biggest;
            biggest = nums[i];
        }
        else if (nums[i] > secondBiggest) {
            secondBiggest = nums[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << biggest << "\t" << secondBiggest;
}
```

Note: We initialized 'biggest' and 'secondBiggest' with 'INT_MIN', therefore, the first and second elements of array can replace these 2 values.